# Error: invalid use of non-static class data member

Tags: c++, vector

All the other examples of this error have got me to a "You have not defined the array size" but I am not using arrays but am using different files and including them.

What I actually want to do is iterate through the 2D vector and get each position's pointer (That's why I need to know the rows and columns)

The error happens every time I use `Map::` in the following code in `Unit.cpp`:

```
#include "Map.h"

Unit Unit::nearest_enemy_finder(){

    vector <Unit *> enemies;

    for(int i=0; i<Map::ROWS; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<Map::COLUMNS; j++){
            if (Map::UNIT_POINTERS[j][i]->UNIT_TYPE != UNIT_TYPE){
                enemies.push_back(Map::UNIT_POINTERS[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return *enemies[0];
}
```

In `Map.cpp` `ROWS` are initialised to `5`, `COLUMNS` are initialised to `10`, `UNIT_POINTERS` is 2D vector of `Unit` pointers: `vector<vector<Unit *> >` and `MAP_SQUARES` is a 2D vector of `chars`: `vector<vector<char> >`

`Map.h`:

```
class Map
{
public:
    Map(string text_file);
    ~Map();

    vector <vector<Unit *> > UNIT_POINTERS;
    vector < vector<char> > MAP_SQUARES;

    int ROWS;
    int COLUMNS;

private:

    void init(string text_file);

    void init_map_from_level(string text_file);

    void init_unit_pointers();
    void init_map_squares();
};
```

However, in `Map.h`, if I put static infront of the variables, I get an error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Map::MAP_SQUARES", referenced from:
      Map::init_map_squares() in Map.cpp.o
      Map::init_map_from_level(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in Map.cpp.o
      Map::set_unit_symbols(int, int) in Map.cpp.o
  "Map::UNIT_POINTERS", referenced from:
      Unit::nearest_enemy_finder() in Unit.cpp.o
      Map::init_unit_pointers() in Map.cpp.o
      Map::init_map_from_level(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in Map.cpp.o
      Map::set_unit_symbols(int, int) in Map.cpp.o
  "Map::ROWS", referenced from:
      Unit::nearest_enemy_finder() in Unit.cpp.o
      Map::init(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in Map.cpp.o
      Map::init_unit_pointers() in Map.cpp.o
      Map::init_map_squares() in Map.cpp.o
  "Map::COLUMNS", referenced from:
      Unit::nearest_enemy_finder() in Unit.cpp.o
      Map::init(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in Map.cpp.o
      Map::init_unit_pointers() in Map.cpp.o
      Map::init_map_squares() in Map.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: show your `Map.h`; how should we know what `Map::` is?

Comment: Imagine we don't follow you around and know every example you've seen, or what you are trying to accomplish. Mind elaborating? Perhaps creating a [mcve]?

Comment: so, first of all: Don't use `ALL_CAP_VARIABLE_NAMES`. These are canonically reserved for macros and constants. Then: This sounds like a recipe for use-after-free and memory leaks. Read about smart pointers and object ownership concepts. Then, there's really no need for `static` members here; if there should only be one instance of a map, make a singleton map factory. If there should be multiple maps, but only one set of enemies, then your object design is bad, and you should keep your enemies outside your map.

Comment: and: I bet your compiler (or more likely, your linker) actually gives you detailed info on what is wrong before that "Undefined symbols" line (or after). You don't even give us all the error messages!

Comment: I gave the error message fully. I don't know what you mean by map factory. And what I actually want to do is iterate through the 2D vector and get each position's pointer. That's why I need to know the rows and columns

Comment: so, read these errors! They point to a different piece of code than you showed us.

Comment: That's if I use static

Comment: And: @StoryTeller is absolutely right. You're not giving us a MCVE (as he asked for); your problem is probably improper initialization, but to see that you'd need to give us a *complete* example that demonstrates the problem, not only this minimalistic reveal of code, every time we ask for more. Getting tired.

Answer (score 0):

The class members that you have defined for class `Map` and that are not `static` are members that depend on an object of the class.

So if you define two Maps:

```
Map a, b;
```

each instance has its own `ROW`:

```
a.ROWS = 10;   // small Map
b.ROWS = 50;   // larger Map
```

If in another object you refer to a member like you did (i.e. `Map::ROWS`) the compiler complains, because you didn't tell which Map object's `ROWS` you meant.

So you have to address a fundamental design issue:  how does an object of the `Unit` class know which `Map` object to use ?

- Should `Unit` have a member reference to the relevant `Map x;` at construction time ?  Then you could clarify: `x.ROW` instead of `Map::ROWS`.
- Should `Unit` be able to find back from a kind of repository ?  Then you could find back the right object and do as above.
- Will you have a single `Map` ?  Then make the members `static`.

If you make these members `static`, it means that they are no longer dependent on a specific object, but shared between all the objects of that class.   IMHO, if you make everything of `Map` static, its no longer a real class in the sense of OOP, but rather a kind of substitute for set of global variables.

But if you go this way, then every static variable must be not only declared in the class definition, but also defined somewhere.  So you must add a statement like:

```
int Map::ROWS;
```

If you just add the `static` keyword, then the compiler will accept it.  If it's not defined in the cpp, it will think that there is some other compilation unit where you'll define it.  However, when the code is linked, at the end of the build process, the linker will not find the symbol, hence the error messages that you observe.

***P.S:*** As someone mentioned in the comments, try to [avoid all caps symbols](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-not-CAPS)

Comment: I only have 1 Map and can only have referenced only one Map::ROW etc... If I do declare the `int Map::ROW;` then I receive the error `non-friend class member 'ROWS' cannot have a qualified name`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it was ROWS.  Did you declare it as static in Map.h and define it at top level in Map.cpp ?

Comment: Not as static as it gave me an error as stated in my question, but I did declare it.

Comment: @MeowWOW this goes in pairs:  Either declare it static in the header AND define it in one of the cpp as described (this will prevent the errors that you've mentioned).  Or define a global `Map` object (i.e. Map `my_global_map;` in one cpp,  and `extern Map my_global_map;` in a header so that it's known int the other files)  and use the object to access the members (e.g. `my_global_map.ROWS`).